# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.data/multi30k/train.fr'

Tags: python, pytorch, machine-translation, torchtext

I'm trying to load `Multi30k` torchtext dataset using google colab. When I load the `.de` it works fine, but as soon as I changed from `.de` I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.data/multi30k/train.fr'
```

This is how I loaded the `.de` and it worked:

```py
train_data, valid_data, test_data = datasets.Multi30k.splits(
    root=".data",
    exts=('.de', '.en'),
    fields = (SRC, TRG),
    
)
```

As soon as I changed this code by changing `.de` to `.fr` the error rises:

```py
train_data, valid_data, test_data = datasets.Multi30k.splits(
    root=".data",
    exts=('.fr', '.en'),
    fields = (SRC, TRG),
    
)
```

#### Imports

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn  import functional as F
import spacy, math, random
import numpy as np
from torchtext.legacy import datasets, data
import time
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

#### Seeds

```py
SEED = 42
np.random.seed(SEED)
torch.manual_seed(SEED)
random.seed(SEED)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(SEED)
torch.backends.cudnn.deteministic = True
```

#### Tokenizers `spacy`

```py
import spacy
spacy.cli.download('fr_core_news_sm')

spacy_fr = spacy.load('fr_core_news_sm')
spacy_en = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def tokenize_fr(sent):
  return [tok.text for tok in spacy_fr.tokenizer(sent)]

def tokenize_en(sent):
  return [tok.text for tok in spacy_en.tokenizer(sent)]
```

#### Fields

```py
SRC = data.Field(
    tokenize= tokenize_fr,
    lower= True,
    init_token = "<sos>",
    eos_token = "<eos>",
    include_lengths =True
)

TRG = data.Field(
    tokenize = tokenize_en,
    lower= True,
    init_token = "<sos>",
     eos_token = "<eos>"
)
```

#### The cell that throws an error

```py
train_data, valid_data, test_data = datasets.Multi30k.splits(
    root=".data",
    exts=('.fr', '.en'),
    fields = (SRC, TRG),
)
```

Comment: Does the file .data/multi30k/train.fr exist?

Comment: Why are you using `google-colaboratory` tag, you haven't mentioned any things about it in your question! Either remove it or mention about it in question!

Comment: @Michael_H isn't that it will be created when i run the cell?

Comment: I don't know. Can you please post the full code with imports so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: @ Michael_H I posted all the current cells that i have so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is no `train.fr` file in the dataset itself.

If you list down what pytorch downloaded,

```
$ !ls -al .data/multi30k
total 5.4M
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 15 14:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jul 15 14:26 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  65K Jul 15 14:26 mmt_task1_test2016.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  69K Oct 17  2016 test2016.de
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  61K Oct 17  2016 test2016.en
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  71K Feb 11  2017 test2016.fr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 2.1M Feb  2  2016 train.de
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 1.8M Feb  2  2016 train.en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jul 15 14:26 training.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  75K Feb  2  2016 val.de
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  62K Feb  2  2016 val.en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  46K Jul 15 14:26 validation.tar.gz
```